# Display a "big" triangle based on input n

Tags: python

So far, I have coded a way to print a triangle based on user input.

```
Input: 2
Output:
 *
***

Input: 3
Output:
  *
 ***
*****
```

My Python code for that is this:

```
row = int(input())

for i in range (1, row + 1):
      for j in range (1, row - i + 1):
            print (end=" ") 
      for j in range (i, 0, -1):
            print ("*", end = "")
      for j in range (2, i + 1):
            print ("*", end = "")
      print()
```

How can I use my current code to get this kind of triangle?

```
Input: 2
Output:
    *
   ***
 *  *  *
*********

Input: 3
            *
           ***
          *****
       *    *    *
      ***  ***  ***
     ***************
  *    *    *    *    *
 ***  ***  ***  ***  ***
*************************
```

I really need someone's help. I have no idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little algorithm that prints what you want. It handles any number of rows :

```
rows = 3
cols = rows * 2 - 1

# Draws one line of a single triangle (the dimensions are given by 'cols' and 'rows')
def printTriangleLine(line, newline = False):
    string = None
    if line < 0: string = " " * cols
    elif line == rows - 1: string = "*" * cols
    else:
        string = " " * (rows-(line+1))
        string += "*" * (line * 2 +1)
        string += " " * (rows-(line+1))

    print(string, end="")
    if newline: print()


# Big triangles are constituted of small triangles drawn with 'printTriangleLine' 
# They have the same dimensions then the little triangles

def main():
    #iterate the big rows
    for row in range(0, rows):
        # iterates the lines within each little triangle (small rows)
        for line in range(0, rows):
            # iterates the big columns
            for i in range(0, cols):
                # finds the blank triangles
                blank = row < rows - 1
                if blank: blank = i < rows - (row + 1) or i > rows + (row - 1)
                # prints adding a newline at the end of the last column
                printTriangleLine(-1 if blank else line, i==cols-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output :

```
            *            
           ***           
          *****          
       *    *    *       
      ***  ***  ***      
     ***************     
  *    *    *    *    *  
 ***  ***  ***  ***  *** 
*************************
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, @dspr! I'm just starting to learn Python and was extremely stuck with this. Thank you again!